# Get taxonomy name used in a current post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Hello I have create a custom taxonomy for a custom post. I want to get the taxonomy term that is used in the current post. How to get it.

Comment: What is the taxonomy?  Can we see your code?  What you want to use is `$term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-taxonomy-here' );`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the taxonomy by post ID:

```
$yourterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , array( 'taxonomy_name') );
foreach ( $yourterms as $term ) {
 echo $term->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
$tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
 
$html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
$html .= "{$tag->name}</a> ";  //this will get the  taxmont term.
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

This will Help You